# Notify users PDF creation is ready and can be downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob, rails-activestorage

Users can create a PDF in my app which takes some time to generate, so it has to be done in a background job. No problem, but then there is a delay and the user must be notified that the PDF is ready.

So the first choice is to send an email with a download link or a push notification in the app itself. My preference is the push notification, so I guess ActionCable is the way to go? My app runs on Heroku, so is ActionCable also a good choice then or is another solution preferable?

Then there is another consideration, where to store the generated PDF until the user downloads it? I could upload it to Azure/S3/etc with ActiveStorage, or I could store it temporarily in an app folder and delete it after download. My preference is to do the last, because the PDF is there only for a few minutes and therefore the hassle to store it in the cloud is not really needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very broad question here, which is very much dependent on the overall user needs and experience you want them to have.

I'll start with the simplest part, in terms of temporary storage of the PDF. There are several things to bear in mind here.

I would say that from a scalability, and application security standpoint, storing the PDF to the cloud is the way to go. Opening up writable directories on your application server carries a risk. Also, if you ever need to scale to more than one server, this will not work. Deleting items from cloud storage is not hard with the appropriate APIs.

Is it essential for the user to be authenticated in some way to download the PDF? This is more challenging if you push the PDF to a cloud bucket (unless you have the PDF named with a very complex, unguessable name, that name only accessed through the authenticated application). If the data is less sensitive, then your email notification can show the link directly, but you won't know easily if a user has retrieved the PDF and it is now ready to be deleted.

In terms of notification, I'd go with email for several reasons. Simplicity is the main one. Do you have experience with ActionCable? It appears simple on the surface, but there are many things to bear in mind when using it: infrastructure and UI being the major ones. Also, from a user experience perspective, are users likely to hang around in the application waiting for the PDF to be completed? What happens if they logout? How will they know the PDF is available?

If the timescale for generation of the PDF is short and absolutely optimized scalability is not a big deal, you could consider a simpler mechanism that checks for user notifications (a simple query onto a user_notifications table for example) for every user action, and use a flash or some other session flag that the UI can check and use to asynchronously retrieve the notification.

Just ideas. Impossible to give definitive answers.